# oh-my-zsh history completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, command-history, oh-my-zsh

I have recently switched to zsh, using [robbyrussell's `oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). Before that i used bash with a lot of custom stuff and i am only missing one thing because zsh is trying to be 'too smart':

If i type `git commit` and then <kbd>↑</kbd> zsh goes through all recent `git` commands. What i really want though, is going through all commands that start with `git commit` (not just `git`).

How can i achieve this behavior in (oh-my-)zsh?

Comment: Strange, I use OMZSH and it does behave like this.  
Do you have 'plugins=(git)' in your zshrc?

Comment: yes i do, but it is not only for git, all commands are completed this way.

Comment: On Ubuntu see https://superuser.com/a/1490192/131522

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem in the [ZSH documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control). Oh-my-zsh seems to map the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> Keys to something like

```
bindkey '\e[A' history-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-search-forward
```

Which yields the exact behavior I described above. The ZSH Documentation describes the behavior of `history-search-backward` as

> Search backward in the history for a line beginning with the **first word in the buffer**.

---

What I wanted instead was the following mapping, which I inserted into my `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '\e[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

The behavior of `history-beginning-search-backward` is as follows:

> Search forward in the history for a line **beginning with the current line up to the cursor**. This leaves the cursor in its original position.

Also, if `\e[A` doesn't work for the up or down arrows, press `<ctrl-v><KEY (e.g., up arrow)>` in another terminal which gives `^[OA`. Then you can use this instead of `\e[A`. The process is described here: http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!! I was going nuts over this

Comment: For non-OMZ user like me: `bindkey` doesn't do anything real, due to a bug, so OMZ team patched it with [this plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/3477ff25274fa75bd9e6110f391f6ad98ca2af72/plugins/safe-paste/safe-paste.plugin.zsh). Simply download it and source it before `bindkey`.

Comment: @FranklinYu you do realize that's total bs, right? that plugin doesn't do anything with bindkey except USE it to catch some events.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect!

Comment: Just an FYI that the link provided is a 404. Try https://zshwiki.org/home/keybindings/ instead. Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

I wanted the same behaviour for zsh with `oh-my-zsh` installed and found plugin `history-substring-search`.

I achieved the same behaviour described above by adding the plugin to my `~/.zshrc`:

> `plugins=(git brew npm history-substring-search)`

I guess this plugin did not exist back when this question was raised. Just an alternate way to achieve the same thing.