# zsh history up-arrow history completion not working

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am not able to get the zsh history keybindings to work the way I'd like.  I'd like to be able to type `sudo` and then use the up arrow to scroll through all history commands with the prefix `sudo`.

I believe this should be `bindkey "^[[5~" up-line-or-history`.  I have that in `lib/key-bindings.zsh` and that file should be sourced.  I am using a largely unmodified installation of [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

I have what I think is the same `.zshrc` and lib files on a VM and history works as I want.  The VM is running  zsh `4.3.10` while my other machine (the one that is not working) is on `5.0.0`.  Is this a version issue?

Answer (score 5):

See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1720

Adding this to .zshrc solved it for me:

```
# start typing + [Up-Arrow] - fuzzy find history forward
if [[ "${terminfo[kcuu1]}" != "" ]]; then
    autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
    zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
    bindkey "${terminfo[kcuu1]}" up-line-or-beginning-search
fi
# start typing + [Down-Arrow] - fuzzy find history backward
if [[ "${terminfo[kcud1]}" != "" ]]; then
    autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
    zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
    bindkey "${terminfo[kcud1]}" down-line-or-beginning-search
fi
```

Comment: Thankyou! This has been bugging me for ages, it always worked on MacOS, but now it's working nicely on my Linux box too

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, if that changed from 4.3.10 to 5.0.0, but the widget you are searching for is called `history-search-backward` in the last few releases.

Also a nice key binding is `history-incremental-pattern-search-backward` where you can input (at a special prompt after invoking that widget) for example `sudo*destdir` to cycle through all commands starting with `sudo` and ending with `destdir`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, my problem ended up being the key mapping itself.  I followed [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/418299/27119) (especially noting the last paragraph) and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on Ubuntu do `echo DEBIAN_PREVENT_KEYBOARD_CHANGES=yes>>~/.zshenv`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what was wrong was that I was copying the following environment vars from bash to zsh:

```
# History modifications
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %T  "
export HISTSIZE=-1
export HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

Removing those in zsh made it work

Answer (score 0):

Changing `export HISTSIZE=` to `export HISTSIZE=999999999` in ~/.zshrc solved the issue for me.